# regex in yahoo pipes to select everything up to a particular word

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

How do I make a regex in yahoo pipes to eliminate everything from the beginning of a field to a particular word?

I am taking the rss from youtube,

http://www.youtube.com/rss/search/%s.rss

and would like to extract the view count and add that as a separate field. The view count is in the description field and appears as:

```
<div><span style="color:#666666;font-size:11px;">Views:</span>
431</div>
```

in this case the number I need to extract is 431.

Thanks,
Pietro

P.S: What follows is part of the description of a recent search. I did not put the whole code because it was too long.

```
<div style="font-size:12px;margin:3px 0px;"><span>a frankly shoddy cover of Susan Cadogan&#39;s big hit! Reminds me of my first &#39;squeeze&#39; at The Hummingbird under 18&#39;s sesh, monkey boots, (couldn&#39;t afford Docs),fred perry t shirt and stapress &#39;champagne&#39; 2 tone trousers robbed from Nelson House....................</span></div></td>
<td style="font-size:11px;line-height:1.4em;padding-left:20px;padding-top:1px;" width="146" valign="top"><div><span style="color:#666666;font-size:11px;">From:</span>
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZ0m4ZjZMNdOl4uyvrQm-yw">TheLastMehari</a></div>
<div><span style="color:#666666;font-size:11px;">Views:</span>
431</div>
<div style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;"><img style="border:0px none;margin:0px;padding:0px;vertical-align:middle;font-size:11px;" align="top" alt="" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/static/images/icn_star_empty_11x11.gif"> <img style="border:0px none;margin:0px;padding:0px;vertical-align:middle;font-size:11px;" align="top" alt="" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/static/images/icn_star_empty_11x11.gif"> <img style="border:0px none;margin:0px;padding:0px;vertical-align:middle;font-size:11px;" align="top" alt="" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/static/images/icn_star_empty_11x11.gif"> <img style="border:0px none;margin:0px;padding:0px;vertical-align:middle;font-size:11px;" align="top" alt="" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/static/images/icn_star_empty_11x11.gif"> <img style="border:0px none;margin:0px;padding:0px;vertical-align:middle;font-size:11px;" align="top" alt="" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/static/images/icn_star_empty_11x11.gif"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace part should like this:

```
^.*Views:\D*(\d+).*$
```

... and replacement part will be just

```
$1
```

In other words, you'll catch all the digits that are separated from `Views:` string with non-digit symbols only - and throw off all the rest.

UPDATE: You should enable `/s` modifier for this to work. An alternative is using 'universal' character class instead of `.`:

```
^[\s\S]*Views:\D*(\d+)[\s\S]*$
```

The replacement part should stay the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I was not very clear, so I re-edited the question. I tried the code you suggested but it did not work. I tried also to replace it with a "pippo" string just to see if it was replacing anything but it looks like it wasn't. Unfortunately even after so much time I have real trouble with regex, so I cannot really say what's wrong :-(

Comment: I am trying to understand your regular expression, and how it works, but I cannot. You seem to say: from the beginning of the file, continue until you reach Views. Then ignore anything which is not numerical after it, then get the first number(s) (and store it in  a variable), and finally ignore everything else? Is that correct? But wouldn't this get the wrong number if the user used the word "Views" somewhere in its description? Wouldn't be more secure using the </Span>?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this? http://rubular.com/r/boubtEmP4s

Comment: It didn't work. But I am afraid it didn't work because I did not explain well the problem. I then edited the question. And the user raina found the working solution faster. Probably the problem was that there also was a newline that I did not notice. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I ended up merging the two suggestions, and using:

```
^[\s\S]*Views:\<\/span\>\s*(\d+)[\s\S]*$
```